# how to get the streak count of the rows within same 5 sec bucket in kdb+q

Tags: kdb

I am trying to get the streak count of the rows which are within the 5 second difference.
for example

```
q)t:([] time:2023.07.10D01:30:23.595000000 2023.07.10D01:31:06.843000000 2023.07.10D01:31:08.482000000 2023.07.10D01:31:10.123000000 2023.07.10D01:31:11.267000000 2023.07.10D01:31:12.348000000;flag:111111b;Id:6#1234)
```

I was trying something like this

```
q)wj1[-0D00:00:05.000000000  0D00:00:00.000000000 +\:t`time;`Id`time;t;(t;(count;`streakCount))]
    time                          flag Id   streakCount
    ---------------------------------------------------
    2023.07.10D01:30:23.595000000 1    1234 1   //1 because first entry
    2023.07.10D01:31:06.843000000 1    1234 1   //1 because the difference >5sec remove oldest entry and add this one
    2023.07.10D01:31:08.482000000 1    1234 2   //2 difference <5sec add
    2023.07.10D01:31:10.123000000 1    1234 3   //3 difference <5 sec add
    2023.07.10D01:31:11.267000000 1    1234 4   //4 difference <5sec add
    2023.07.10D01:31:12.348000000 1    1234 4   //4 1:31:12.348000000-1:31:06.843000000 is 5>sec so remove the oldest entry
```

this solution checks the difference from the oldest entry in the bucket and the latest one for 5 sec. if it's not less than 5 sec it'll remove the oldest from the bucket.
however I am looking for it to check with consecutive difference of 5 sec.
output should be

```
|time                          |flag |Id  | streakCount|
|2023.07.10D01:30:23.595000000 |1   | 1234| 1   //1 because first entry|
|2023.07.10D01:31:06.843000000 |1    |1234| 1   //1 because the difference >5sec between this and prev one|
|2023.07.10D01:31:08.482000000 |1    |1234| 2   //2 difference <5sec add|
|2023.07.10D01:31:10.123000000 |1    |1234| 3   //3 difference <5 sec add|
|2023.07.10D01:31:11.267000000 |1    |1234 |4   //4 difference <5sec add|
|2023.07.10D01:31:12.348000000 |1    |1234| 5   //5 1:31:12.348000000-01:31:11.267000000 is 5<sec so add|
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to reset the streak count if a row does not occur within 5 seconds of the previous row:

```
q)update streakCount:1+1{y*x+y}\00:00:05>deltas time from t
time                          flag Id   streakCount
---------------------------------------------------
2023.07.10D01:30:23.595000000 1    1234 1
2023.07.10D01:31:06.843000000 1    1234 1
2023.07.10D01:31:08.482000000 1    1234 2
2023.07.10D01:31:10.123000000 1    1234 3
2023.07.10D01:31:11.267000000 1    1234 4
2023.07.10D01:31:12.348000000 1    1234 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If only looking back one row you can use `deltas` and `scan`

```
update streakCount:1+{$[y;x+y;y]} scan `long$(deltas time)< 0D00:00:05 from t
time                          flag Id   streakCount
---------------------------------------------------
2023.07.10D01:30:23.595000000 1    1234 1
2023.07.10D01:31:06.843000000 1    1234 1
2023.07.10D01:31:08.482000000 1    1234 2
2023.07.10D01:31:10.123000000 1    1234 3
2023.07.10D01:31:11.267000000 1    1234 4
2023.07.10D01:31:12.348000000 1    1234 5
```